# Service account oAuth with Google Contacts API

Tags: oauth, google-contacts-api

I am trying to fetch Contacts in my account using the Google Contacts API in a command line app. The only oAuth option that makes sense for my command-line drive open source application (http://asynk.io/) is the Service Account model. The recent shutdown of the ClientLogin functionality without adequate documentation or support on how to use Service Account authentication is quite painful. I have not managed to get my code to work again.

I am using the following code to access my contacts. The rest of my code to pull contacts / folders remains the same. However now I am not getting any of the contacts in my account.

```
    em  = self.get_client_email()
    key = self.get_private_key()
    scope = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds'

    gdc = gdata.contacts.client.ContactsClient(source='ASynK')
    credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(em, key, scope)
    auth2token = gdata.gauth.OAuth2TokenFromCredentials(credentials)
    auth2token.authorize(gdc)
```

I have seen other questions similar to this, and the earlier problems were supposedly related to the Contacts API not being available in the API Console. However that is not the case now. I can see Contacts API on that console and it is enabled for my account.

Has anyone managed to successfully use the Contacts API after the ClientLogin was shutdown?

**EDIT**

From further research it appears like it the contacts accessible via the Service Account linked to a normal gmail.com address is for that app itself,and not of that linked account, which is bizarre from my point of view.

Comment: Are you using the flow that relies in user consent? I.e., is your app displaying the consent URL to the user?

Comment: The Service Account flow does not rely on user consent because there is no third party user.